# @FeignClient interface in application's one dependency and @EnableFeignClients on application main class can't load the interface as bean

Tags: java, feign

For example:

Application A -> dependency B. B got a `@FeignClient` annotated SPI interface, which is `@Autowired` depended by classes **both** in A and B, the SPI is expected to be works fine when application A is started.

Adding `@EnableFeignClients` and `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= "path-include-that-SPI-interface")` on A's main class and start, encounters an exception that "Cannot find bean qualified... [SPI interface]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is configuring scan base-path for `@EnableFeignClients`: `@EnableFeignClients(basePackages= "path-include-that-SPI-interface")`.